# Does the US president have the authority to ban TikTok?

Tags: united-states, internet

Donald Trump, the president said that he wants to ban TikTok. Would such a ban violate the first amendment? If not does he have the power to act via executive order or does it have to go through Congress?

Comment: Tiktok is banned in India but India is a different country...

Answer (score 2):

He has that power, as spelled out [here](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-securing-information-communications-technology-services-supply-chain/), relying primarily on [50 U.S.C. 1701](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/50/chapter-35). This executive order already exists, so one path is to simply put Tik Tok on the [Commerce Department's entity list](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/lists-of-parties-of-concern/entity-list). The specific list as of July 22 is [here](https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/documents/regulations-docs/2326-supplement-no-4-to-part-744-entity-list-4/file) – you can find Huawei already on the list, for example. A First Amendment lawsuit is not likely to succeed, since there is no First Amendment right to directly or indirectly threaten national security, foreign policy, and the US economy (the compelling government interest). The courts will generally defer to the executive branch in its judgment regarding the necessity of a restriction. You could argue (as a proponent of Bytedance's side) that it is only necessary to ban the program on military devices, but the counter-argument is that a less restrictive action is not effective in addressing the compelling governmental interest.

Comment: There *is* a 1st Amendment concern here; the right of individuals to run whatever code they want (because a number of decisions say code is speech), and to associate with whom they want (e.g. other TikTok users). Of course government interest may override that, but I don't think it can be dismissed out of hand.

Comment: The 1st Amendment certainly does not let you run whatever code you want. Look at the DMCA. Part of it protects copyright, which is in the Constitution, but part of it makes running code that circumvents digital locks illegal.

Comment: @PaulJohnson In *Bernstein,* the Court said encryption software was speech, and could be published. It said nothing about running code.

Comment: @Justaguy True, but the effect of running code is arguably part of its expression. Imagine if the law allowed the production of a movie but prohibited running it through a projector. While there is no actual precedent on the point, this does not imply that there is no 1stA issue.

Comment: @Oliver You can run the code, its just illegal to use it to circumvent copy protection on a copyrighted work. The DMCA also forbids the distribution of circumvention tools. All this is part of the copyright exception to the 1st Amendment.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_free_speech_exceptions#Speech_owned_by_others

Comment: @PaulJohnson The circumvention of copy protection IS the running of code. Maybe you mean that you can run code EXCEPT code that breaks digital locks. My point was just that not all code can be run. And no, it does not violate copyright to break a lock. If it were then Congress would not have been purchased to pass the DMCA because software companies could have just sued digital lock breakers for copyright infringement.